# Pourquoi est-ce que « toutes » est un pronom dans cette phrase

Tags: pronoms, adverbes, tout-tous

Il s'agit du numéro 5 ici: https://parlez-vous-french.com/tout-tous-toutes-toute-comment-choisir/.

> 5. Elle vend toutes ses affaires. Elle les vend ___

En particulier, j'ai mis « tout » parce que je pensais que en ce cas, ce devrait être un adverbe, parce qu'il modifie « vend ».

Mais apparement, la bonne réponse est « toutes » parce que, selon les commentaires ci-dessous, c'est un pronom, et il doit être accordé avec « les » qui est féminin et pluriel.

Cependant, il y a déjà un pronom, non? En ce cas, « les » est un pronom, donc, je suis un peu confus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C'est similaire à ce qui se passe avec *en* et des groupes nominaux quantifiés: le groupe nominal est réduit à un pronom verbal, mais le quantificateur reste présent là où était le groupe nominal:

- J'ai trois bagages -> J'en ai trois __
- J'ai quelques bagages -> J'en ai quelques uns __
- J'ai certains bagages -> J'en ai certains __
- J'ai tous les bagages -> Je les ai tous __

Comme on peut le voir par le changement de forme de quelques (uns) et de prononciation de tous (/tu/ -> /tus/), on a bien affaire là à des pronoms.

En simplifiant un peu, les syntacticiens formalistes diraient que "toutes ses affaires" ou "quelques bagages" ont une structure comme (GQ(GN)) où chaque groupe quantifié contient un déterminant (toutes/quelques) et un groupe nominal (ses affaires/bagages), qui lui-même peut contenir un déterminant (ses/ø) et un nom (affaires/bagages).

*Les* et *en* sont la forme pronominale des groupes nominaux internes de ces groupes quantifiés, ce qui laisse tous et quelques privés d'un groupe nominal qui dépendrait d'eux. Mais comme il s'agit de déterminants (qui en français doivent normalement obligatoirement avoir un dépendant), il ne peuvent pas rester isolés et sont convertis dans les pronoms correspondants, /tus/ et quelques uns.

Answer (score -2):

**I** « Toutes » est un adjectif et il est caractérisé comme suit dans le [TFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/toutes), en ce qui concerne la première occurrence.

> I. Adjectif  indéfini
>   B. [Marque l'idée de totalité]
>   1. [Précède un détermnant. au pluriel ou bien un pronom]

« Toutes » précède un déterminant dans ce cas ; « Ses » est le déterminant dont il est question ; voici un tableau de tous les déterminants : https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-1853.php

**II** Lorsque « toutes » remplace la barre, c'est un pronom ; l'indication de cela est que aucun nom ne suit « toutes » ; donc ce mot est mis pour un proupe nominal et ce groupe est « toutes ses affaires ».

In case you are familiar with English here is some comparison.

In English you'd say "She is selling all of them.". "All" stands for "toutes" and "them" for "les" ("them" is the object case, in French it is "les".). The difference is that in English there is an added "of" but you do have, anyway, another pronoun. The slight divergence in the syntax changes little to the logic in the two languages, which is roughly the same.